# TypeError: intlProvider.getChildContext is not a function

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, react-intl

I'm using injectIntl in my react functional component to achieve the localization.
I'm using enzyme/jest to do the unit test. I've copied the intl-test-helper file, but got error: 
" TypeError: intlProvider.getChildContext is not a function "

I've tried other suggestions from stackflow:
1. remove mock file --- which I don't have mock file
2. use const { IntlProvider } = jest.requireActual("react-intl"); to force it use the actual one , not mock --- not working.

the react component is: WarningModal.jsx:

```
import { FormattedMessage, injectIntl } from "react-intl";
.......

const WarningModal = ({
  .........
  ...props
}) => {
  ........

export default injectIntl(WarningModal);
```

the intlTestHelper.js file is :

```
 * Components using the react-intl module require access to the intl context.
 * This is not available when mounting single components in Enzyme.
 * These helper functions aim to address that and wrap a valid,
 * English-locale intl context around them.
 */

import React from "react";
import { IntlProvider, intlShape } from "react-intl";
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme"; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies

/** Create the IntlProvider to retrieve context for wrapping around. */
function createIntlContext(messages, locale) {
  const { IntlProvider } = jest.requireActual("react-intl");
  const intlProvider = new IntlProvider({ messages, locale }, {});
  const { intl } = intlProvider.getChildContext();
  return intl;
}

/** When using React-Intl `injectIntl` on components, props.intl is required. */
function nodeWithIntlProp(node, messages = {}, locale = "en") {
  return React.cloneElement(node, {
    intl: createIntlContext(messages, locale)
  });
}

/**
 * Create a shadow renderer that wraps a node with Intl provider context.
 * @param {ReactComponent} node - Any React Component
 * @param {Object} context
 * @param {Object} messages - A map with keys (id) and messages (value)
 * @param {string} locale - Locale string
 */
export function shallowWithIntl(
  node,
  { context } = {},
  messages = {},
  locale = "en"
) {
  return shallow(nodeWithIntlProp(node), {
    context: Object.assign({}, context, {
      intl: createIntlContext(messages, locale)
    })
  });
}

/**
 * Mount the node with Intl provider context.
 * @param {Component} node - Any React Component
 * @param {Object} context
 * @param {Object} messages - A map with keys (id) and messages (value)
 * @param {string} locale - Locale string
 */
export function mountWithIntl(
  node,
  { context, childContextTypes } = {},
  messages = {},
  locale = "en"
) {
  return mount(nodeWithIntlProp(node), {
    context: Object.assign({}, context, {
      intl: createIntlContext(messages, locale)
    }),
    childContextTypes: Object.assign({}, { intl: intlShape }, childContextTypes)
  });
}
```

here how I use it to test:

```
import React from "react";
import { _WM as WarningModal } from "../components/WarningModal";
// import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { mountWithIntl } from "../utils/intlTestHelper.js";

describe("<WarningModal />", () => {
  const props = {
    discardChanges: jest.fn(),
    saveChanges: jest.fn(),
    closeWarningModal: jest.fn(),
    intl: { formatMessage: jest.fn() }
  };

  it("should have heading", () => {
    const wrapper = mountWithIntl(<WarningModal {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(".confirm-title")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

error:

```
 ● <WarningModal /> › should have heading

    TypeError: intlProvider.getChildContext is not a function

      14 |   const { IntlProvider } = jest.requireActual("react-intl");
      15 |   const intlProvider = new IntlProvider({ messages, locale }, {});
    > 16 |   const { intl } = intlProvider.getChildContext();
         |                                 ^
      17 |   return intl;
      18 | }
      19 | 

      at getChildContext (src/utils/intlTestHelper.js:16:33)
      at createIntlContext (src/utils/intlTestHelper.js:23:11)
      at nodeWithIntlProp (src/utils/intlTestHelper.js:60:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/WarningModal.spec.js:29:21)
```

please shine some lights on this. Thank you.

Comment: updated the test file to :https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/Testing-with-React-Intl.md#-advanced-uses-injectintl; it works.

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of react-intl `getChildContext` has been deprecated and may generate this error. You can use the following instead:

```
import { createIntl } from 'react-intl';

const intl = createIntl({ locale: "en",
    messages: {
        message1: "Hello world"
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

`React-Intl` has replaced `IntlProvider.getChildContext`, with the `createIntl` for testing purpose, while migrating V2 to V3.

> We've removed IntlProvider.getChildContext for testing and now you can use createIntl to create a standalone intl object outside of React and use that for testing purposes. See Testing with React Intl for more details

Here is the [Link](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x/)

So the working code for this is

For resolving this error, you have to create custom shallow component. Like as

```
    import { createIntl } from 'react-intl';

    const LocalLanguage  = {
       french:{},
       arabic:{},
       english:{}
    }
    const lang = getCurrentLanguage('en', LocalLanguage);
    const intl  = createIntl({ locale: 'en', lang }, {});

    export const shallowWithIntl = (node) => {
        return shallow(nodeWithIntlProp(node), { context: { intl } });
    }
```

If this not helps, then you can define the following function, in your helper file.

```
    const messages = require('./Lang/en.json') // en.json 
    const defaultLocale = 'en'

    const locale = defaultLocale

    export const intl = (component) => {
         return (
             <IntlProvider
                 locale={locale}
                 messages={messages}
             >
                 {React.cloneElement(component)}
             </IntlProvider>
         );
    }
```

And use it in your test files as below

```
    const wrapper = mount(intl(<MobileRechargeComponent />));
```